# gnuplot conditional 'using' causes broken x-axis

Tags: gnuplot

Tracking the battery discharge / charge on my phone. Data shaped like a 'V'. Charge percentage and elapsed time in seconds, like this:

```
100,0
74,8103
51,15304
24,23407
2,30609
23,33286
55,37360
76,40064
100,44132
```

Here's how I'm processing *n* files and plotting them together:

```
plots=""
my_xrange=0

files=system("ls -1B data/*.csv | sort -k2 -t '-'")
do for [ file in files ] {
    this="'".file."' ".'using ($2/3600):1 notitle, '
    plots=plots.this
}
eval('plot '.plots)
```

(happy plot elided because of too many links)

Then the boss comes by and says the "uphills" are distracting, can I plot just the "downhills" pretty please? No worries, `stats` will give me the minima, so I `xrange`. Woot!

```
plots=""
my_xrange=0

files=system("ls -1B *.csv | sort -k2 -t '-'")
do for [ file in files ] {
    stats file using ($2/3600):1 prefix "STATS" nooutput
    if ( STATS_pos_min_y > my_xrange ) { my_xrange = STATS_pos_min_y }
    this="'".file."' ".'using ($2/3600):1 notitle, '
    plots=plots.this
}
print sprintf( 'stats: plot xrange is %.2f', my_xrange )
set xrange [0:my_xrange]
eval('plot '.plots)
```

[xrange obliterates some uphills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt6Qp.png)

I *know* there's got to be a way to just not plot the uphills, so I wind up with `using` conditional.

```
this="'".file."' ".'using (($2/3600) <= STATS_pos_min_y ? $1 : 1/0) notitle, '
```

which *does* effectively kill the uphills, but does two bad things to the plot:

1. the X axis values don't match the previous plot
2. the plot lines are merged on top of one-another

[broken things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G7Xe.png)

I need to use $2/3600 because I want things to be expressed in terms of hours. Oh, sure, I could write a script to massage the data before it even gets to gnuplot, but that's admitting defeat.

What have I not understood in my use of `using`?

Comment: I do not understand what the "two bad things" are that you mention... Could you post the two data files that you used for yoru "broken things" image, and explain what you would like to get instead?

Comment: OMG sorry! I composed this last night and then kernel panic. 

I plot data as is (blue line) and thru a conditional that only displays the "downslope" part of the data (purple line). I EXPECT the purple to exactly overlay the blue for the downslope part of the data. What's happening is the conditional values seem to be halved, which makes no sense to me.

Output: http://imgur.com/a/se4yy
Data: shown above in original post

Comment: set terminal svg size 512,384 \
 fname "Gill Sans" fsize 9 rounded dashed linewidth 1 background rgb 'white'
set datafile separator ","
set key font ",6"

file="frustration.csv"
set output 'foobar.svg'

 stats file using ($2/3600):1 prefix "STATS" nooutput
 plot \
  file using ($2/3600):1  with linespoints, \
  file using ($2/3600):1:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", ($2/3600), $1)) notitle with labels center offset 3.4,.5, \
  file using ((($2/3600) <= STATS_pos_min_y) ? $1 : 1/0) with linespoints

Comment: Questions:

(1) Why does the conditional output seem to be halved?
(2) How can I plot data conditionally *with* labels?

Also, why was my markdown completely ignored? Sigh...

Comment: Edit: sorry, can't get a code block by any means :-/ proper code at https://gist.github.com/mickeys/738d49f69b10073d926c6af2188c3f9e

Answer (score 2):

The plot command for your whole data (purple line) is

```
plot file using ($2/3600):1  with linespoints
```

while that for the conditional data (blue line) is

```
plot file using ((($2/3600) <= STATS_pos_min_y) ? $1 : 1/0) with linespoints
```

This `using` statement selects only those data points for which `($2/3600) <= STATS_pos_min_y`. However, you do not specify where on the x-axis those data points should be plotted, so gnuplot assumes it's just the line number in the data file (0,1,2,3,4). You have to specify the position on the x axis just like you did in the unconditional plot:

```
plot file using ($2/3600):((($2/3600) <= STATS_pos_min_y) ? $1 : 1/0) with linespoints
```

should do it.

By the way, formatting is rather limited in SO comments. To post code it's usually better to edit the question where you have more formatting options.